# Why am I getting zero for all values in this expression?

Tags: c++

Following is a fragment of a program for deducing whether or out 2 lines intersect.
`P and P2` are `CPoint` objects marking the start and end point of one of the 2 lines.

```
double m1,m2;  //slopes
double b1,b2;     //y-intercepts
double y,x;     //intersection point

m1=(max(P.y,P2.y) - min(P.y,P2.y)) /( max(P.x,P2.x) - min(P.x,P2.x) );
```

For some reason I'm always getting `m1` to be `0`. Why's that?

Comment: Are the variables even initialized? Either that or you're experiencing integer division.

Comment: It might be because of integer division. Is y and x declared as double in the CPoint class?

Comment: I also suspect integer division rounding errors.

Comment: P and P2 are actually arguments passed to that function. I tried making all variables `int`s . But that just gives me `m1` to be `0`, instead of `0.000..`

Comment: Also, instead of doing `max(...) - min(...)`, why not just writing `abs(P.y-P2.y)`?

Comment: We are talking about the `CPoint::x` and `y` members, not your *local variables*.

Comment: Did you try splitting up the expression in smaller segments and compiling them separately? This would help a lot.

Comment: Use temporaries to inspect what's going on, but the solution was mentioned here already, integer division truncates fractional parts. `static_cast` to float in order to get floating-point division.

Comment: @leemes, or just abs((P2.y-P.y)/(P2.x-P.x)), but just make sure the right abs gets used.

Comment: you know, i have a sneaky suspicion he's just trying to find the slope (m1).  all the min and max is because he wants to shuffle so that x goes in order, not knowing that it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @thang Actually, his code calculates the absolute slope, not the mathematically correct (signed) slope. `m = dy / dx` is the correct formula, not `m = |dy| / |dx|`

Comment: @leemes, i know, that's why i suggested abs((P2.y-P.y)/(P2.x-P.x)), which would be faster than |dy|/|dx| as |dy|/|dx|=|dy/dx|, but i speculated that he really wants the slope but does this by mistake.  To determine whether 2 lines intersect, one method (which is not robust) is to find the m (slope) and b (intercept) for both lines and solve the equation (x_icept = (b2-b1)/(m1-m2), assuming there is an intercept and neither line is not vertical).  The abs of the slope doesn't help to find intersection.

Comment: @ thang You're right, that's what I'm doing. And yes, like you said, I was making the mistake of calculating the absolute slope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `CPoint` class is a point with integer coordinates, you have to do some conversion here to get the result you want. See the following demonstration of the problem. Consider two points `P = (1, 4)` and `P2 = (5, 3)`:

```
m1=( max(P.y,P2.y) - min(P.y,P2.y) ) / ( max(P.x,P2.x) - min(P.x,P2.x) );
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           4               3                    5               1
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                   1                                   4
```

However, in integer division, `1 / 4` is `0`, but you want the result to be `0.25`. The fact that the result variable has a type of `double` doesn't change the value (and type) of the *expression*.

To solve this problem, you have to *cast* the parts of your expression just before it becomes *relevant* that they are to be considered as non-integral numbers. In your case this are the operands of the division, so that it will be a floating point division. (Casting the result of the division will also not help.)

```
m1 = static_cast<double>( max(P.y,P2.y) - min(P.y,P2.y) )
   / static_cast<double>( max(P.x,P2.x) - min(P.x,P2.x) );
```

Note that casting the second operand is optional, as `double / int` always uses floating point division.

**Also note that your expression calculates the *absolute* value of the slope. You might want to calculate the *signed* slope.**

---

Something you can improve in your code (this won't solve the problem above): Instead of subtracting the min of the max of the difference, just take the absolute value of the difference:

```
m1 = static_cast<double>( abs(P.y - P2.y) )
   / static_cast<double>( abs(P.x - P2.x) );
```

Since in C++, `abs` is a template function (in C it's a macro, urgh...), you can also force a result type using explicit template types:

```
m1 = abs<double>(P.y - P2.y)
   / abs<double>(P.x - P2.x);
```

Also, as the calculation of a slope between two given points seems to be a commonly used function, you can implement this as a free-standing function on two `CPoint`s:

```
double absoluteSlope(const CPoint & p, const CPoint & q) {
    return abs<double>(p.y - q.y) / abs<double>(p.x - q.x);
}
```

Even better, to make use of C++ templates, implement it on a generic class which has the members `x` and `y`:

```
template<class T>
double absoluteSlope(const T & p, const T & q) {
    return abs<double>(p.y - q.y) / abs<double>(p.x - q.x);
}
```

This solution now works for your `CPoint` instance with integer coordinates as well as a (maybe upcoming) `CPointF` class with float / double coordinates.

**As already warned above, this calculates the absolute slope.** To change this to a mathematically correct (signed) slope, just replace `abs` with `static_cast`:

```
template<class T>
double slope(const T & p, const T & q) {
    return static_cast<double>(p.y - q.y) / static_cast<double>(p.x - q.x);
}
```

Comment: it may depend on which version of min and max he's using.

Comment: @thang I just hope `std::min/max` or any other templated version, everything else would be horrible.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked beautifully :) I took your advice of switching over to abs().

Comment: @Ghost I added a warning, see my edit. If you want the signed slope, don't use `abs` but rather `static_cast`, the rest will be the same.

Comment: @leemes Since you brought the concept of an absolute slope up, I just realized that `max()` or `min()` don't really matter at all. It's only a plain slope that I want, not an unsigned one. So I guess I can drop the `abs()`.

Answer (score 0):

The division A/B should A/(double)B. Use this in your code.
Fabs instead of abs too.